# I need (Query) get data Descending Order from corda Vault Query

Tags: corda

If anyone can help me its lots help.

**I need Query Some state that state data must be descending Order**

Answer (score 0):

You can add sorting to your query; see below sample code that's taken from [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.6/api-vault-query.html#query-for-consumed-deal-states-or-linear-ids-specify-a-paging-specification-and-sort-by-unique-identifier).

```java
Vault.StateStatus status = Vault.StateStatus.CONSUMED;
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Set<Class<LinearState>> contractStateTypes = new HashSet(singletonList(LinearState.class));

QueryCriteria vaultCriteria = new VaultQueryCriteria(status, contractStateTypes);

List<UniqueIdentifier> linearIds = singletonList(ids.getSecond());
QueryCriteria linearCriteriaAll = new LinearStateQueryCriteria(null, linearIds, Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED, null);
QueryCriteria dealCriteriaAll = new LinearStateQueryCriteria(null, null, dealIds);

QueryCriteria compositeCriteria1 = dealCriteriaAll.or(linearCriteriaAll);
QueryCriteria compositeCriteria2 = compositeCriteria1.and(vaultCriteria);

PageSpecification pageSpec = new PageSpecification(DEFAULT_PAGE_NUM, MAX_PAGE_SIZE);
Sort.SortColumn sortByUid = new Sort.SortColumn(new SortAttribute.Standard(Sort.LinearStateAttribute.UUID), Sort.Direction.DESC);
Sort sorting = new Sort(ImmutableSet.of(sortByUid));
Vault.Page<LinearState> results = vaultService.queryBy(LinearState.class, compositeCriteria2, pageSpec, sorting);
```